# Why is Linq query setting my Arithabort options to false?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-entities, sql-server-2012

I have code like this:

```
using (var db = new MyDataContext()) {
  db.ExecuteStoreCommand("Set Arithabort on");
  var q = AFairlyComplexQuery(db); // returns an IQueryable<>
  var result = q.ToList();  // Line 4
  return result;
}
```

I was finding that this query was timing out.  I ran SQL Profiler and grabbed the SQL and ran it in SSMS, and it came back in 7 seconds.  From past experience, I've learned that this is invariably being caused by the `Arithabort` option being set to `0`, which is why I run that first command.  But it's still timing out.

I put a breakpoint on Line 4.  When I hit the breakpoint, I went to SSMS, and ran the following query:

```
SELECT arithabort, * FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions s
WHERE program_name LIKE 'MyProg%'
```

As expected, `Arithabort` is set to `1`.  Then I stepped over Line 4, and immediately went back to SSMS to run that query... and suddenly `Arithabort` has been set back to `0`!

Why?  How to fix this?

**EDIT:**  Well, I found a workaround, and it's more or less an answer, but not very satisfying.

```
using (var db = new MyDataContext()) {
  db.Connection.Open(); // INSERTING THIS LINE PRESERVES ARITHABORT
  db.ExecuteStoreCommand("Set Arithabort on");
  var q = AFairlyComplexQuery(db); // returns an IQueryable<>
  var result = q.ToList();  // Line 4
  return result;
}
```

I inserted a line `db.Connection.Open()`.  Now `Arithabort` maintains its original value.  But that doesn't explain (a) why this is, and (b) why it's still running roughly 10 times longer than it takes in SSMS...

Comment: Can it be that your MyDataContext starts a transaction and ends the transaction at Dispose? So your command will be rolled back when something fails.

Comment: @wonko79 - Arithabort is reset before the dispose.

Comment: And you also tried executing the command in an own context and the query in an own context afterwards.

Comment: @wonko79 It seems no matter what I do, even for the simplest Linq queries, Arithabort is implicitly reset to 0.  Tested in the simplest of tests, and behavior is consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a known issue that EF sets `Arithabort` off.  And for some reason, `ExecuteStoreCommand` doesn't work, while the following code does work:

```
var cmd = ((EntityConnection)db.Connection).StoreConnection.CreateCommand();
cmd.Connection.Open();
cmd.CommandText = "set arithabort on";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16438169/7850) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16438007/7850) for more.