# How to set Arithabort on in Linq to Entities?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I've found tons of answers for how to set Arithabort on in Linq to SQL, but nothing in Linq to Entities.  In Linq to SQL, you can do this:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)){
  cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
  cmd.Connection.Open();
  cmd.CommandText = "set arithabort on;";
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Line 5
  using (var db = new MyDataContext(conn)) {
    ...
  }
}
```

but if I do exactly the same thing, just substituting `EntityConnection` from `SqlConnection` in the code snippet above, I get a runtime error on Line 5:

> The query syntax is not valid. Near identifier 'arithabort', line 1, column 5.

I'm guessing it's connected to the fact that Linq2Sql is hardwired for SQL Server, whereas EF can work on other DBs.  So what's the trick?

Comment: not sure if it's available for EF5, but : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344992/controlling-arithabort-in-ef4

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus - I have downloaded the solution from that blog.  I just cannot bring myself to believe that it is so difficult and complicated to do something so simple.

Comment: If you've got a query that runs slowly in entity framework, but quickly in ssms the problem may be parameter sniffing, I had this same problem and solved it after reading these two posts: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9840/why-would-set-arithabort-on-dramatically-speed-up-a-query/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962789/entity-framework-cached-query-plan-performance-degrades-with-different-parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SqlConnection` is not specific to linq-to-sql or EF, you can still use the code with EF. But you must create an EntityConnection that receives the SqlConnection.

`EntityConnection.CreateCommand` creates an [`EntityCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entitycommand.aspx), which expects Entity SQL as command text, no raw SQL commands.

An alternative is to use the context's `ExecuteStoreQuery` command (ObjectContext), or `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` (DbContext).

Comment: How do you create an `EntityConnection` that "receives" the `SqlConnection`?  I did try using `ExecuteStoreQuery`, and that ran, but my query performance is still over 10x slower than when I run it in SSMS, which makes me think that there's some kind of black magic happening behind the scenes that is still treating arithabort as off.

Comment: There is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679371.aspx) overload, but that's probably not too convenient because of the `workspace` parameter. Ten times slower is surprising, I don't know why that happens.

Comment: And how do you get a `DbContext` object from an `ObjectContext`?

Comment: You can use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696505%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) constructor.

Comment: You can also try `((EntityConnection)context.Connection).StoreConnection.CreateCommand()`

Comment: I used `((EntityConnection)context.Connection).StoreConnection.CreateCommand()` and that worked!  Dunno why `context.ExecuteStoreCommand` wasn't effective - but this worked!  Thanks!